Android Webview how to display outlook mail in portrait layout in landscape device?
I have a android webview application and tried to load outlook.com.
i have few mixed of portrait and landscape devices.
in both the devices outlook layout is displaying differently as shown in below images.
Image1 is in portrait device.

Image2 is in Landscape device.

is there any way i can show the same kind of layout in both the devices like portrait one.
i.e i want to display the layout shown in image1 (portrait device) in landscape device also?
here i have tried by setting the User agent but it didn't help.
is there any way that i can show the same kind of layout in both the devices like portrait one.
i.e i want to display the layout shown in image1 (portrait device) in landscape device also?

Try adjusting WebView settings like:
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true)

or
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true) 

to control viewport behavior. Experiment with these settings to see if they improve layout consistency.

Yes i have already used these settings but no use.

@Jeremy Caney
Any idea would you share with me?

@RajendraPrasad: Unfortunately, no. This isn’t my area of expertise. I was just fixing the formatting of the answer as part of StackOverflow’s review process.
